How to embed font in Adobe LiveCycle Designer XDP Form to be imported to SAP HANA Public Cloud?
How can I embed a font (for example, Khmer and LeelawadeeUI) to the XDP file in Adobe LiveCycle Designer without installing the font on the machine? I will import the XPD file later to SAP HANA Public Cloud. Is there any other solution to embed font for SAP HANA Public Cloud?
Reference:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_CLOUD/a630d57fc5004c6383e7a81efee7a8bb/da488f76078447b0b42792226cfcf9b1.html
So far, I only managed to embed the font to the PDF file, but the SAP HANA Public Cloud is required to use the XDP format
